# Read/write a link in a cell using the Google Sheets API?

Tags: hyperlink, google-sheets-api

I am using the Google Sheets API to manipulate a spreadsheet.  Some cells contain links, where the text shown differs from the underlying link.  When I read them with the Google Sheets API, I only get the text.  Is there any way to get the underlying URL?  Or to write a link to a cell that has differing text content?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I have not found a way to read link contents, but you can write links with "=HYPERLINK(url, text)", if you use the USER_ENTERED valueInputOption when updating a sheet.